# If a set is open (closed) in $R^m$ is it also open (closed) in $R^{m\pm 1}$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following two propositions true or false:

1 - If A is an open (closed) subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$, then

\begin{equation}
\{x ∈\mathbb{R}^m : (0,x) ∈ A\} 
\end{equation}

is open (closed) in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

2 - If A is an open (closed) subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, then

\begin{equation}
\{(0,x) ∈\mathbb{R}^{m+1} : x ∈ A\} 
\end{equation}

is open (closed) in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$.

To prove the first proposition true I have proceed in the following way:

Since A is open $\forall(0,y)\in A$, $\exists r>0$ such that $B((0,y),r) \subset A$. Now, every $(0,z)\in B((0,y),r)$ also belongs to $A$ and:

\begin{equation}
 d((0,z),(0,y))<r
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{(0-0)^2+(z_1-y_1)^2+...+(z_m-y_m)^2}<r
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{(z_1-y_1)^2+...+(z_m-y_m)^2}<r
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 d(z,y)<r
\end{equation}

Hence we can construct the ball $B(y,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Since $(0,z) \in A$, then $z \in \{x ∈\mathbb{R}^m : (0,x) ∈ A\} $, and consequently all the points in the ball B(y,r) also belong to the set, this is $B(y,r) \subset \{x ∈\mathbb{R}^m : (0,x) ∈ A\}$. With this it is proven that the set $\{x ∈\mathbb{R}^m : (0,x) ∈ A\}$ is open.

By the same reasoning and starting from the fact that $A^c$ is open I have also proven it true for the case in which A is close.

Could you confirm me if these proofs are correct?

For the second proposition in the case in which A is open I have proven it false directly by a counterexample. However, I am a bit lost for the case in which A is closed. I have been analyzing some examples and I have the intuition that it is true but I am not able to formally prove it. Could you give me some hints about how to proceed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics). You can use the Chebyshev distance instead of the euclidean distance to make easier the calculations.

Comment: 2) can clearly be seen not to be true.  {(0,x)| x in (a,b)} is clearly not open. Although 0x [a,b] is closed.

Comment: 2) for closed.  If X is closed and and (a,y) a ne 0 then (a,y) is not limit point of 0xX as we can find neighborhood of radius < |a|.  If b is not limit point of X then (0,b) not limit point of 0xX obviously.  So only limit points of 0xX are( 0,z) where z is limit point of X.  X closed so z in X so (0,z) in 0xX so 0xX clised.  So true.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks! Perhaps it is a little advanced for what I was looking, but I will definitely check the Chebyshev distance to see if it makes it easier!

Comment: @fleablood Thanks! I was thinking on something like that! But could you clarify to me the sentence "If X is closed and and (a,y) a ne 0 then (a,y) is not limit point of 0xX as we can find neighborhood of radius < |a|."?

Comment: Yeah. Let N = {(w,z)| d ((w,z)(a,y) < r} for some r < |a|/2.  Then if (w,z) in N then |w-a| < d ((w,z), (a,y)) < |a|/2 so w \ne 0 so (w,z) is not in 0xX.

Comment: re Chebyshev distance.  Seriously, distance calculations are the *least* important aspect of these proofs.  If you can use an abstract d(x,y) all the better.  But the is a concept of metrics being equivalent if they yield the same open sets.   Basically if you can always find r,s,t so that $N(x,d_1, r) =\{y|d_1(x,y) < r\} \subset N(x,d_2, s) = \{z|d_2(x,z) < s\} \subset N(x,d_1,t) = \{w|d_1(x,w) < t\}$ then all open sets with one metric will be open with the other metric.

Comment: ... because an interior point having an open ball with one metric entirely in the set means there is also an open ball with the other metric entirely in the set.  So the point is interior in one iff interior in both.  d1(x,y) = max (|x_i - y_i|) and d2(x,y) = root (sum(x_i - y_i)^2) are two such equivalent metrics as:  if x is such that |x_i - y_i| < e then root(sum(x_i- y_i)^2) < e and if root(sum(x_i - y_i)^2 < e the |x_i - y_i| < root(2) e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2).

If $A = (a,b)$ is open then $B = \{(0, x)|x \in (a,b)\}:= \{0\}\times (a,b)$ is clearly not open in $\mathbb R^2$ as every open neighborhood of $(0,x)$ will contain some $(\epsilon, x')$ where $\epsilon \ne 0$ so  $(\epsilon, x') \ne \{0\}\times (a,b)$ so $(0,x) \in \{0\}\times (a,b)$ is not an interior point.

So 2) is not true for open sets.

....

But if $X $ is closed in $\mathbb R^m$ then $W= \{0\}\times X$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{m+1}$.

Let $(w,z) \in \mathbb R^{m+1}; i.e. w \in \mathbb R; z \in \mathbb R^m$ where $w \ne 0$.  Then let $0 < \epsilon < |w|/2$.  If $N((w,z), \epsilon) = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb R^{m+1}| d((a,b),(w,z)) < \epsilon\}$ then if $(a,b) \in N((w,z), \epsilon)$ the $|a - w| = d((a,z),(w,z)) \le d((a,b),(w,z)) < \epsilon < |w|/2 < |w| = |0 - w|$ so $a\ne 0$ so $(a,b) \not \in \{0\}\times X$.

So $(w,z)$ is not a limit point of $W$.

If $z \in \mathbb R^m$ is not a limit point of $X$ then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ so that $N(z,\epsilon)$ contains no point of $X$.  Then $N((0,z),\epsilon) \subset \mathbb R \times N(z,\epsilon)$ contains no point of $W \subset \mathbb R \times X$.

So $(0, z)$ is not a limit point of $W$.

So the only limit point of $W$ must be of the form $(0, z)$ where $z$ is a limit point of $X$.  As $X$ is closed, $z \in X$ so $(0,z) \in W$.  So all limit points of $W$ are in $W$.

So $W$ is closed.

So 2) is true for closed sets.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Now I see it totally clear. What do you think of my proofs for the first claim?

Comment: Yes, your proofs of the first claim are good.